# Enviar argumentos o parametros desde un #selector en Swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode

Tengo un problema, cree unos botones en una celada de un UITableView, mi celda tiene una clase donde se crean los IBoutlets de mis labels y de mis botones, y en el metodo cellForRowAt asigno mi celda de la siguiente forma:

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PostViewCell
```

el problema que tengo es que cuando quiero usar uno de los botones que cree de esa celda hago lo siguiente:

```
cell.btnLike.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addLike(idPost:idLike:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

lo hago de esta forma para poder acceder a una funcion que se llama addLike que recibe dos parametros:

```
@objc func addLike(idPost: Int, idLike: Int){
        print("Like")
    }
```

Como estoy haciendo uso de un #selector a mi funcion le agrege el @objc para que pueda ser utilizada dentro de ese selector, ahora mi problema es que no se de que forma puedo pasarle los dos parametros osea algo similar a esto:

```
#selector(addLike(idPost: 1, idUserPost: 2))
```

si lo hago de esta forma me marca un error, mi duda es, como puedo pasar dos parametros desde el #selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede enviar parámetros según la documentación de Apple.
La mejor manera de trabajar es con `Protocolos`. Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo:

**PostViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

protocol ProtocolPostViewCell {
    func onClick(idPost: Int, idUserPost: Int)
}

class PostViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tuButton: UIButton!

    var postViewDelegate: ProtocolPostViewCell? = nil
    var idPost: Int = 0
    var idUserPost: Int = 0

    @IBAction func tuFuncion(_ sender: Any) {
        postViewDelegate?.onClick(idPost: self.idPost, idUserPost: self.idUserPost)
    }
}
```

**TableViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class TuTableViewController: UITableViewController, ProtocolPostViewCell {
     var idPost: [Int] = //Los valores los obtienes de algún lado
     var idUserPost: [Int] = //Los valores los obtienes de algún lado

    func onClick(idPost: Int, idUserPost: Int) {
        //Obtienes los valores del botón que hiciste click
        print(idPost)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PostViewCell
        cell.postViewDelegate = self //Asignas al delegate para que se active las función al hacer click
        cell.idPost = self.idPost[indexPath.row]//Asignas valores
        cell.idUserPost = self.idUserPost[indexPath.row]//Asignas valores
    }
}
```

De esta manera el botón de cada `fila` tendrá un identificador único asignado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta ya intente implementar la solcuion que propones pero al dar clic en mi botón este siempre me imprime 0, no esta recibiendo los valores que le estoy pasando

Comment: Perdon, olvida mi comentario anterior, estaba enviando mal yo los valores, ya funciona sin problemas, muchas gracias :D

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y funciona perfecto. Asignaste la clase `PostViewCell ` a la celda de tu tableView por la Interfaz o lo hiciste por código? Yo lo tengo por código.

Comment: Si, ya lo probé, fue error mio, estaba un poco confuso pero ya funciona a la perfección, gracias a tu respuesta ya puedo entender como configurar otros dos botones mas

Comment: esa variable var postViewDelegate: ProtocolPostViewCell? se debe declarar como weak para evitar retain cycle

Comment: Exactamente, es una regla general. No lo puse en el código para no confundir, podría editar la respuesta si lo necesitas.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, 
Te recomiendo usar closures, tomando el ejemplo de la persona de arriba el código seria el siguiente.

PostViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit


class PostViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tuButton: UIButton!

    var actionButtonTapped : ((Int , Int) -> ())?
    var idPost: Int = 0
    var idUserPost: Int = 0

    @IBAction func tuFuncion(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let actionButtonTapped = actionButtonTapped else {return}
        actionButtonTapped(self.idPost , self.idUserPost)
    }
}
```

TableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class TuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
     var idPost: [Int] = //Los valores los obtienes de algún lado
     var idUserPost: [Int] = //Los valores los obtienes de algún lado

    func onClick(idPost: Int, idUserPost: Int) {
        //Obtienes los valores del botón que hiciste click
        print(idPost)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PostViewCell
        cell.idPost = self.idPost[indexPath.row]//Asignas valores
        cell.idUserPost = self.idUserPost[indexPath.row]//Asignas valores
        cell.actionButtonTapped = {[weak self] (idPost , idUserPost) in
           print(idPost, idUserPost)
}
    }
}
```

considera que closure es la mejor solución para tu caso porque solo estas pasando una función, usualmente yo uso los protocolos cuando uso mas funciones en las que quiero delegar la responsabilidad